# Vue build fails on Heroku when using Lerna

Tags: node.js, vue.js, heroku, npm, lerna

Trying to host a Lerna monorepo with Express backend + Vue frontend on Heroku. Components are contained inside `/packages/server` and `/packages/frontend` respectively. The intention is to build the Vue frontend during deployment and host it as static content through Express.

./package.json

```
{
  "name": "my_app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "bootstrap": "lerna bootstrap",
    "start": "lerna run start --stream",
    "postinstall": "npm run bootstrap",
    "build": "lerna run build --stream"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lerna": "^3.20.2"
  }
}
```

My build-phase fails due to

```
lerna notice cli v3.20.2
lerna info Executing command in 2 packages: "npm run build"
       frontend: > frontend@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_c2cbb32af790fe0e5e4852ce2bcab8e0/packages/frontend
       frontend: > vue-cli-service build
frontend: sh: 1: vue-cli-service: not found
frontend: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
frontend: npm ERR! syscall spawn
frontend: npm ERR! file sh
frontend: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
frontend: npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
frontend: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
```

A standalone Vue repository does not fail its build-phase in this way, so the issue is most likely something going wrong with `lerna bootstrap` or how Heroku builds things, but I haven't been able to figure out what the issue is.

Similar setup for create-react-app does not fail, possibly due to `react-scripts` being a regular dependency.

Is there some gotcha that I am missing with Lerna and devDependencies, or is this an issue with Vue?

Answer (score 1):

Few days later I finally figured out what was wrong with the setup. The problem is two-fold:

First, it seems that there is possibly an issue with vue-cli@4.3.0, as even starting a standalone project will fail to build with `NODE_ENV=production` due to all the required dependencies being included as devDependencies.

```sh
npx @vue/cli create test
cd test
export NODE_ENV=production
npm install
npm run build
```

For local development, `lerna bootstrap` adheres to the NODE_ENV as expected and even devDependencies get installed. When running it as part of a CI though, devDependencies are skipped.

As to why a standalone Vue project builds on Heroku without any issues, this is detailed in the nodejs buildpack [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support)

> By default, Heroku will install all dependencies listed in package.json under dependencies and devDependencies.

The buildpack only works for a single-tier package, so as soon as you have nested packages in a monorepo layout, the nested devDependencies do not get touched.

Moving the Vue dependencies out of devDependencies solved my build issues for now.